# Relatório C# RLDC - Group

Tags: c#, relatório

Possuo duas tabelas: Produto e Categoria. Gostaria de exibir todos os produtos, agrupados por suas categorias.

Estou usando o Parent Group e funciona perfeitamente, mas gostaria de exibir a descrição da categoria, contida na tabela da mesma, ao invés do ID. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Que banco de dados você esta usando?

Comment: SQL Server. Estou usando o Report View

Comment: e você que fazer o agrupamento no sql server ou no report view?

Comment: Preciso fazer o agrupamento no report view mesmo

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/12b6f318-13d1-4b94-9d04-f0f3a45958a2/rdlc-repetir-cabealho-do-grupo-quando-h-uma-quebra?forum=reportingservicespt#f4a9219b-3b9f-4bb1-bb8e-060db6cc19d0. Da uma olhada, é um tópico que eu respondi, acho que você vai conseguir seguir com isso.